# Elasticsearch - Document better score when more words matching

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem and hope that anybody can help me.

I've got a simple example for a search with a match query

```
"query": {
    "match": {
        "filterValues": "ordner ohne griffloch"
    }
}
```

I got exactly two hits:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "filters",
    "_type" : "filter",
    "_id" : "F-114150068-1170182",
    "_score" : 5.420828,
    "_source" : {
      "filterValues" : [
        "Ja",
        "Griffloch vorhanden",
        "Griffloch",
        "mit Griffloch"
      ]
    },
    "highlight" : {
      "filterValues" : [
        "<em>Griffloch</em>"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "filters",
    "_type" : "filter",
    "_id" : "F-114150069-1170182",
    "_score" : 4.452639,
    "_source" : {
      "filterValues" : [
        "ohne Griffloch",
        "kein Griffloch",
        "Nein"
      ]
    },
    "highlight" : {
      "filterValues" : [
        "<em>ohne Griffloch</em>"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

My problem is: I want to find the second hit "ohne Griffloch" as the first one (better score), because it matches with more words. But I find the first one with a better score, I think because it contains more often "Griffloch".

I can't use a term query, because then I won't find anything because it doesn't match exactly anything, when the query contains other words (here: "ordner").

Are there any ideas?

Thank you!

For information the index-configuration:

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "lowercase_shingle": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_shingle"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_shingle": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "max_shingle_size": 4
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "filter": {
      "properties": {
        "filterValueId": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "filterValues": {
          "type": "text",
          "position_increment_gap": 100,
          "analyzer": "default",
          "search_analyzer": "lowercase_shingle"
        },
        "categoryId": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: please share your full `query` structure

Comment: Which structure do you wish? I have everything I typed in, except the highlight for the fields, which I removed.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a boost on a phrase matching in your query. So document where all your query terms are found in one of the multiple filterValues will be naturally boosted.

But you need to watch out for this quirk ([see here, official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_multivalue_fields_2.html))

I dont know how (maybe the force is with you), but your mapping is already correct  for the `position_increment_gap` but you should remove the setting

> search_analyzer": "lowercase_shingle"

as it seems a bit strange in your context.

Then we add the boost on match phrase

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "filterValues": "ordner ohne griffloch"
                    }
                }
            ],
            should: [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                        "filterValues": {
                          "query": "ordner ohne griffloch",
                          "slop": 10 
                        }

                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it works!

EDIT after comment :

If you change you mapping to add a sub field with your shingle_analyzer at index time

```
"mappings": {
    "filter": {
      "properties": {
        "filterValueId": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "filterValues": {
          "type": "text",
          "position_increment_gap": 100,
          "analyzer": "default",
          "search_analyzer": "lowercase_shingle",
          "fields": {
              "shingled": {
                   "type": "text",
                   "analyzer": "lowercase_shingle",
              }
          }
        },
        "categoryId": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You could then add a boost on the shingled subfield with this query

```
{
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "filterValues": "ordner ohne griffloch"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                should: [
                  {
                    "match": {
                            "filterValues.shingled": "ordner ohne griffloch" 
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

It will boost in your example the second doc and not the first

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The lowercase_shingle search_analyzer is from another problem which is from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412408/elasticsearch-find-document-by-term-which-is-only-part-of-given-query-stringttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412408/elasticsearch-find-document-by-term-which-is-only-part-of-given-query-string But when I understand match_phrase correctly, all parts of the query must be present. "ordner" will never be present and that's why, it won't boost. Are you sure this should work? I tried it (boost 500), and got the same result as before.

Comment: oops, i missed that :( this will not work you are right

Answer (score 0):

I solved I by using a function-score query with custom script with painless.

This script becomes the full search term and do 2 things:
Set the score based on the length of the value (so here "ohne griffloch" is larger than "griffloch", so better).

The second (optional, but for me good) thing is, it uses the position of the value in the text.

What I needed to do was, remove the array of values and put every value in the index as one document.

```
"functions": [
              {

                "script_score": {
                  "script": {
                    "source": "def v=doc['filterValue'].value; def score = 10000; score += v.length(); score -= \"ordner ohne griffloch\".indexOf(v)*50;",
                    "lang": "painless"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "score_mode": "multiply",
            "boost_mode": "replace",
            "max_boost": 3.4028235e+38,
            "boost": 1
          }

  }
```

Comment: What if I'm doing a multi_match search with multiple fields??